# Webview App as default browser

Tags: android

Hey I have made a browser app for android,
but now I need to give the user a change to set my browser as default.

**EDIT:**
I have tried to use this code in my manifest but with nu luck

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
</intent-filter>
```

But with no luck

Comment: register your app as a listener to url sharing events like explained here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624315/make-android-app-listen-to-shared-links

Answer (score 1):

Try to add following XML to your main activity to make your app a candidate for intent sent by other apps that look for loading a page into the browser with startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://....")));

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: can still not make it as my default browser