# Android - register my application to handle URL

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I register my application to be an http and https handler?

For example, if the user clicks on a link in a text message. I want my application to be displayed in the list of apps that the link can be opened with.

Also, how do I handle the retrieving of the URL passed to my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this?
[Make Android app listen to shared links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624315/make-android-app-listen-to-shared-links)

I think when you put this in the manifest, open the app, the link will be given to you in the app.

No thanks, just some googling! xD

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't asking for code. I just couldn't find much on google.

Comment: How is it given to you in the app?