# Android App-Index Opening Play Store

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-indexing, google-search-platform

So I've been playing around with deep linking and I've got that sorted (Urban Airship). I'm looking at app indexing from Google search results and I'm struggling to get it going. For now, I've got a basic web server up with page with links that *should* open the app / deep link. However, all it does is open the Play Store page of the app...

This is the link on the page:

```
<a href="intent://app.com/product/1#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.package;end">Deep Link</a>
```

Obviously with my package etc.

This is my intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
        android:scheme="http"
        android:host="app.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

Why is it opening the Play Store and not my app?

Thanks

Comment: you should refer this answer. hope this might help you  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21727055/1576416

Comment: Even adding "pathPrefix", it still doesn't work. And my setup is otherwise the same as the link. Not sure why it defaults to the Play Store and not the app installed?

Comment: is your app installed from playstore?

Comment: It is. Solved it though, Intent Filter was not on the right activity...

Comment: @Boots Can you show your updated code together?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Turns out my Intent Filter was not on the right activity.