# Launch my android app when i open my site in mobile browser

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Hey I want my website url to open my android when the user open this url in the browser 
What i did is

```
       <intent-filter>
            <data android:host="www.example.com" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

        </intent-filter>
```

and my webiste url is `www.example.com`

but it doesn't work 
any way on how to achieve this 
Thanks

Comment: what do u mean? u want to open a url from your android app ?

Comment: no i want to launch my android app from browser when i type this url www.example.com

Comment: i tried what provided their but it doesn't work

Comment: I guess you should change `<data android:scheme="https" />` to <data android:scheme="http" />, if your site is not secured.

Comment: @KishorPawar my website is secure

Comment: try `www.example.com://` in your mobile browser. This should work.

Comment: @KishorPawar tried this but same result

Comment: add `android:exported="true"` to your Activity in manifest and then type `www.example.com://` in your mobile browser

Comment: tried it same also doesn't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21663001/launching-custom-android-application-from-android-browser-chrome/21727055#21727055

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Add `data` tag in `<intent-filter>` with `host`

```
<intent-filter>
                <data android:host="www.example.com" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"
                      android:host="www.example.com" />
     </intent-filter>
```

Comment: i tried it with no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine your `<data>` elements into one:

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com" />
```

Comment: but my website url scheme is https not http

Comment: @Tony just set it to https instead...

Comment: @Karakuri i tried but it doesn't work also as there any thing else i should use with and handler or something for this intent ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via href, example

```
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

**Link:** 
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Comment: but i can navigate from my website to specific app page and now i want to open my app at the launch of the website

Comment: @Ashish   Are you sure?

Comment: It will be security breach!!,Browser has very limited authorization as compared to an app.

Comment: No man you can launch your app from the browser url

Comment: i think you meant google now not browser

Comment: No, I meant chrome browser

Comment: yes you are right, poor ignorant me : https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Comment: delete your answer before you get downvotes