# Android app to app using uri schme and return value

Tags: android

In Android, I am trying to call another dummy app from my app via dummy app's uri scheme.

And from the dummy app, when the user click on a button, I want to come back to my app with a return value.

Do you think it's possible?

In Dummy App, I make the configuration as follow:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data
                android:scheme="myapp"
                android:host="my-poc-application.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/id" />
</intent-filter>
```

And from my app, I try to re-direct to my dummy app:

```
String scheme = "myapp";
String host = "my-poc-application.com";
String id = "8";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(scheme + "://" + host + "/" + id);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

// Verify it resolves
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

// Start an activity if it's safe
if (isIntentSafe) {
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

But the dummy app is not called.

Comment: Yes, this is possible in android. So what is the question now?

Comment: Thanks @KaushikBurkule. My question now is how to do it in code? I updated my question with code. Can you help?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending ?

Comment: You need to make sure your second app must listen to your call. Try this in your second app https://stackoverflow.com/a/8624447/7639056

Comment: My question is to redirect to a dummy app by using dummy app's uri scheme. Not like what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt :

Register the intent filter in your activity of your target app:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="target-app"
                    android:host="target-app.com" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Note: You don't need the pathPrefix

In the target application's main activity:

```
btnGoBack.setOnClickListener{
            val resultIntent = Intent()
            resultIntent.putExtra("Result", "I am the result from target app")
            setResult(1000, resultIntent)
            finish()
        }

//Read the id you sent while calling this app
            val uri = intent.data
            Toast.makeText(this, uri?.path.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Note: uri?.path will contain the /id you pass, in your example, 8

Now, in the parent app, from where you will call this target app:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnOpen.setOnClickListener{
            val scheme = "target-app"
            val host = "target-app.com"
            val id = "8"
            val uri = Uri.parse("$scheme://$host/$id")
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)

            // Verify it resolves
            val activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
            val isIntentSafe = activities.size > 0

            // Start an activity if it's safe
            if (isIntentSafe) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == 1000){
            Toast.makeText(this, data?.getStringExtra("Result"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

The activity has a button named `btnOpen`.

In the `onActivityResult`, we get the result we sent from the target app.

This code is in kotlin, and converting it to java should be trivial.

If you have any other questions, do tell.

Regards,

Priyabrata

Comment: Thank you for the code. I have to put the target package name into the intent, it will work. In your code, you don't, and it's still working for you?